# How can I tell when it's a good time to buy a MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro

I want to know if a particular date (for instance, October 1, 2010) is a good date to go ahead and buy a Macbook pro, or whether I should wait few months for new models to come out. How can I figure out whether a computer I buy will soon become obsolete?

Comment: This is a "forum-like" question. Not a Q&A one. This question will be obsolete in 2 weeks or 2 hours :-)

Comment: You could try to reword your question to something like "Is <date> a good time to buy a Macbook Pro". So that people can answer base on the schedule Apple usually follow when launching or upgrading products. But even then, it may be too localized considering the secrecy around Apple's product.

Comment: ok I've edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MacBook Pros aren't going to be updated until at least January, if you can wait 3 or 4 months, I suggest you do so.

However, if you need it before the end of the year, go for it. I doubt we'll see any major advancements anyway. You'll only miss out on slight speed bumps not a [quantum computer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computer).

Comment: "MacBook Pro's aren't going to be updated until at least January" ... really? :-(

Answer (score 4):

See the comments to improve the question, but [Macrumors' buyers' guide](http://buyersguide.macrumors.com/) always has suggestions if now is a good time to buy.

Comment: yeah i know about macrumors. I think we are just in the middle of the cycle, but I wanted to hear opinions of Apple users.